# want to count files from a directory in same project by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a HTML page where I need to count of files present in the specific folder in same project package, I tried to write the code in javascript but have not succeeded yet. Most of the question threads mention about "ActiveXObject" to be used but that itself does not work for me.  Reference: JavaScript: Read files in folder  Can anyone help me in achieving this? Please Suggest any Idea if this can't be achieved only by javascript lang.

Comment: Clientside JavaScript is not build to be able to access Serverside files. You could make an AJAX call to to a serverside file, which in turn could figure out how many files where in a specific folder.

Comment: Please share what you have done yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML + JavaScript in your case is frontend technologies unless you use javascript as backend(nodejs) you won't be able to read project folder contents.